# In Dart language, can method member implement outside of class body?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a short of Find a primeNumber simple code below.

```
void main() {
  PrimeNumber primeNumber = new PrimeNumber(17);
}

class PrimeNumber {
  int remainder;
  int numberToCheck;

  PrimeNumber(this.numberToCheck){...}
  bool findingPrime(int numberToCheck){...}
}
```

Once the findingPrime method have been declared inside class body, I wonder, If it can implement outside class body. unlike C++ or Java use

```
bool PrimeNumber::findingPrime(){...} // it show error in Dart
```

Comment: What is your goal?  Are you trying to make a class declaration where the interface can be easily read without wading through implementation details?  Are you trying to reduce indentation in your function definitions?  For this particular prime number case, there's no need to use a class at all.

Comment: I just want to know the Dart allow us declare method as class member and implement the methode body outside the bracket class field or in global field just like C++.